# Typescript errors in VS 2013

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm using TypeScript in Visual Studio 2013.  I used npm to install tsd and then am using the tsd command to download type definitions.  I get intellisense when typing but then after a line is typed I get the red squiggly and an error that "could not find symbol x" (replace x with ng, angular, etc).  I can control-click and go to the definition so obviously Visual Studio can find the source definitions, but the compiler cannot.  Screenshot below shows the errors in a .ts file I created for my directive.  Any ideas what I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: Try to reference angular.d.ts

Comment: Have tried that, and I get a tool tip saying unnecessary duplicate reference.  The reference to angular.d.ts is within tsd.d.ts

Comment: Check your ts compiler version and angular.d.ts version from github

Comment: Thanks, this led me to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file needs to reference angular.d.ts.  Also the code for setting the values is incorrect.  Instead of `restrict: "E"` for example, it should be `public restrict = "E";`.  The colon tells Typescript it's a type definition.

I am curious though why I need the angular.d.ts reference and why tds.d.ts wouldn't work since it in turn would reference angular.d.ts.  Is it typical to put a reference to the d.ts file at the top of every angular file?  If so that could be quite a bit for my project with over 150 angularjs files.

Here is the final working code:

```
///<reference path="../../../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />

module eStore.PromoCode {
    export class PromoCodeDirective implements ng.IDirective {
        public restrict = "E";
        public templateUrl = "Scripts/Checkout/PromoCode/promoCode.html";
        public scope = {};
        public controller = "PromoCodeController as vm";

        static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
            return () => new PromoCodeDirective();
        }
    }

    angular.module("eStoreCheckout").directive("dccPromoCode", PromoCodeDirective.factory());
}
```